# Polymer list not updating to toggle content

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I have a list of events. Each event has a name. When the name input field is empty, it is visible. When the user is done working with it, they can press 'enter' and it will hide the input field and show its respective **span** instead. If they wish to edit the field again, they can click on the **span** to reveal the input field.

I'm using Polymer 1.6. Here's the code I'm working with:

**HTML**

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{referralEvents}}" index-as="index" id="referralEventsElement">
  <span hidden$="{{!item.name.inputHidden}}" item-index="{{index}}" on-tap="showInput">{{item.name.value}}</span>
  <input hidden$="{{item.name.inputHidden}}" placeholder="Name Session" value="{{item.name.value::input}}" on-keypress="checkForEnter" item-index="{{index}}>
</template>
```

**JS**

```
Polymer({
  is: 'create-referral-event',
  properties: {
    referralEvents: {
      type: Array,
      value: [{
        name: {
          value: "Event 1",
          inputHidden: true
        },
        {
        name: {
          value: "Event 2",
          inputHidden: true
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  checkForEnter: function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
       this.referralEvents[e.target.itemIndex].name.inputHidden = true;
    }
  },
  showInput: function(e){
    this.referralEvents[e.target.itemIndex].name.inputHidden = false;
  });
```

The value changes just fine, but it doesn't update the list to hide or show the elements. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why, but only the `this.set()` method worked for me:

```
showInput: function(e){
  this.set([
     'referralEvents',
     e.target.itemIndex,
     'name',
     'inputHidden'], false);
}
```

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the inspiration, @tomasz-pluskiewicz. I tested this out and it can also use a dot delimited string in place of an array to access the object and change it.

```
showInput: function(e){
  this.set('referralEvents.' + e.target.itemIndex + '.name.inputHidden', false);
}
```

Comment: Yes, both work. I just personally prefer the array overload. String concatenation is so passé ;)